# How to prevent hiding a last link on antd nav bar [React]

Tags: css, reactjs, navbar, antd, vite

I'm struggling to solve a problem about antd nav bar on React.
As you can see below, a name of the last link which go to 'Contact' page is '...' regardless of the size of screen.
[image]

When a cursor hovers over the '...', 'contact' link appears.
[image]

I need to remove '...' and display all links on the navbar.

Here is Header.jsx

```
    function Header(){
    const [openMenu, setOpenMenu]=useState(false);
    const toggleDrawer=()=>{
        setOpenMenu(!openMenu);
    }

    return(
        <div>
            <div className="navComp">
                <div className="logo">
                    <Typography.Title>logo</Typography.Title>
                </div>
                <div style={{float:'right'}}
                className='hamburgerIcon'
            >
               <MenuOutlined style={{color:"black", fontSize:30, }}
                onClick={()=>{
                    setOpenMenu(true);
                }}
                
               />
            </div>
            
            <div className="horizontalMenu">
                <NavigationBar/>

            </div>

            <Drawer 
                placement='right'
                open={openMenu}
                onClose={()=>{
                    setOpenMenu(false);
                }}
                closable={true}
                onClick={toggleDrawer}
                bodyStyle={ {backgroundColor:"blue"}}
    
            >
                {openMenu&&<NavigationBar isInline/>}

            </Drawer>
            </div>
            <Outlet/>
        </div>
    )
}

function NavigationBar({isInline=false}){
    const [current,setCurrent]=useState('h');
    const onClick=(e)=>{
        console.log('click',e);
        setCurrent(e.key);
    }

    return(
        <div >
           
            <Menu 
                style={{border:'none'}}
                onClick={onClick} selectedKeys={[current]} 
                mode={isInline?"inline":"horizontal"}>
 
                <Menu.Item key="h">
                    <Link to="/">Home</Link>
                </Menu.Item>
                <Menu.Item key="a">
                    <Link to="/about">About</Link>
                </Menu.Item>
                <Menu.Item key="p">
                    <Link to="/project">Project</Link>
                </Menu.Item>
                <Menu.Item key="c">
                    <Link to="/contact">Contact</Link>
                </Menu.Item>

            </Menu>
       
        </div>
       

    )
```

Here is Header.css

```
    .navComp{
    padding: 0 50px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}.horizontalMenu {
    flex: right;
    width: 600px,
}
.logo {
    width: 100px;
    float: left;
}

@media (max-width:700px) {
    .horizontalMenu {
        display: none;
    }
}
@media (min-width:700px) {
    .hamburgerIcon {
        display: none;
    }
}
```